# flutter firebase: Admin update user status

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, admin, updates

This is kinda difficult but I would be glad if someone helps.
I have an app connected with admin panel.

The breakdown is like this:

1. Mobile App:
   The user signs up with those authentication staff and the data it's stored in firebase database in a collection called 'users'.
   The collection contains the fields 'name', 'email', 'profile photo', 'status', etc.
   The user then goes ahead to upload his/her government provided document for verification. This document is uploaded to database in a subcollection called 'Document'. This is a subcollection of the collection 'users'. It also contains the same field as the parent collection 'users' plus an additional field called 'document' for the uploaded government document(This is for easy access when getting info from the collection). The field 'status', which is by default 'Not verified' is changed to 'pending verification'. Everything works perfectly.
2. The admin panel:
   Now in the admin panel, the admin can get all the users and also those users who have submitted their docs for verification.
   Now in accessing the info from the subcollection 'Document', I want that at a click of a button the field 'status' of that particular user in the main collection (users) updates from 'pending verification' to 'verified'.

How do I do that?

This is how the admin panel accesses the main collection 'users' users on a screen.

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? selectedUser;
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                
                stream:
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedUser = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                              });
                            },
                            title: Text(
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('Full name'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Text('Error');
                  } else {
                    return const Center(child: Text('Do requests yet'));
                  }
                },
              ),
```

And this is how the admin panel accesses the subcollection 'Document' on a different screen:

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? pendingVerifications;
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collectionGroup('Documants')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(ElevatedButton( onPressed: () {}, child: const 
                 Text('Approve')),
                   )
```

This is the function I tried to write in the 'onPressed' parenthesis but didn't work. (Thus, when the admin clicks on the button it should execute this of that particular user)

```
CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
ref.doc().update({'Status': 'verification'});
```

[user collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J3yJ.png)
[Documents subcollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv39k.png)

Pleae help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
final uid = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['UID'];
ref.doc(uid).set({'Status': 'verification'}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

It is important to use `set` with `SetOptions(merge: true)` so that other fields are not changed.

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.